# Map, groupby, list of values

Tags: java, dictionary, group-by, multimap

Given, one ordered map, `<string,list<sting>>` :

```
k1 [v1,v2,v5]
k2 [v1]
k3 [v4,v5]
k4 [v2]
```

and also set of strings[buckets]  :

```
v2 v4 v5
```

And Output is a map :

```
v2 [k1,k4]
v4 [k3]
v5 [k1, k3]
```

Order is important in output.
Could there be a better way then simple brute force, programming language is java ??

Comment: iterate though original map, if value contains given buckets, add to that bucket. merge all the buckets.

Comment: Well, you can use a `Collector` (java 8)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the map and collect the values into a `SortedMap` holding `SortedSet`s (e.g., a `TreeMap` of `TreeSet`s), leaving the ordering and duplicate process to the underlying data structure:

```
Map<String, List<String> input = ...;
Set<String> buckets = ...;
SortedMap<String, TreeSet> output = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String> entry : input) {
    List<String> possibleBuckets = entry.getValue();
    for (String possibleBucket : possibleBuckets) {
        if (buckets.contains(possibleBucket) {
            Set<String> set = output.get(possibleBucket);
            if (set == null) {
                set = new TreeSet<String>();
                output.put (possibleBucket, set);
            }
            set.add (entry.getKey());
        } 
    }
}
```